# How to make mouseover function break mouseleave?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
    $(".box").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).find(".desc").animate({ "color": "#fff", "backgroundColor": "#1d2a63" }, 200);
    });
    $(".box").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find(".desc").animate({ "color": "#747474", "backgroundColor": "#fff" }, 800 );
    });
```

It's working but I want to stop animation within mouseleave when the user goes back to an element. 
Here's a scenario: mouse is over box, it's changing OK, you're leaving and the 800 ms animation is being played, but when you go back over the box during this time, you have to wait until the animation finishes and then the mouseover is displayed. It's not looking good.

Comment: CSS `:hover` will suit you better

Comment: Agreed with Sterling, no need for Javascript here.

Comment: But I want to have the transition animated...

Comment: try `.stop().animate(...)` in your mouseover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tony's comment is right. But as stated before, you don't actually need JS to do it, CSS could help, like that (vendor-prefixes not included for brevity):

```
.box {
    color: #747474;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.box:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1d2a63;
    transition: all .8s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.stop()` function in the mouseover handler to halt any animations that are running on the object(s):

```
$(".box").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).find(".desc").stop().animate({
        "color": "#fff",
            "backgroundColor": "#1d2a63"
    }, 200);
});
```